# Resettable accumulator behaviors?

Tags: haskell, frp, reactive-banana

I'm trying to wrap my head around FRP and I'm not sure that I'm doing it right. I want to build up a string from key press events up until enter is pressed. Once enter is pressed, the string gets written out and the accumulator is reset to the empty string.

I have a event source that emits a `Char` every time a key on the keyboard is pressed, `ePressed`. First, I separate out the two kinds of key presses I care about:

```
eWritable = filterE (`elem` ['A'..'z']) ePressed
eEnter = filterE (== '\n') ePressed
```

Now I know how to gather them together into what I want to send out:

```
eToPrint = accumE "" (fmap (:) eWritable)
```

But I'm not sure how to "hold on to" this until enter is pressed, or how to reset it afterwards. What's the right, idomatic way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that `eToPrint` is sort of a union of two events: when you press characters and when you press enter. Here an example (reactive-banana 0.8):

```
eToPrint = accumE "" $ unions [(:) <$> eWritable, const "" <$> eEnter]
```

To "hold" it, you can use a `Behavior`.

---

Here is a complete solution:

```
bString = accumB "" $ unions [(:) <$> eWritable, const "" <$> eEnter]
eOut    = bString <@ eEnter
```

The behavior `bString` contains the accumulated `String` value. The `eOut` event returns the last string value whenever the `eEnter` event happens. Note in particular the semantics of `accumB`: At the moment in time where `eEnter` happens, the value of `bString` is still the *old* value.

Comment: as one of the best sources on FRP, and the best on reactive-banana, could you please elaborate a bit further? +1 if yes!

Comment: @ErikAllik Like this?